# IF with ClientDetailTemplateId

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

It is possible to add condition to linq in asp.net

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<>().
Name("myUniqName").
Columns(columns => {
  columns.Bound(p => p.Title).Width(100).Title("Mytitle");
  columns.Bound(p => p.Text).Width(250).Title("Txt").ClientTemplate("#=Text#");
}).
 if (number == 1){
   .ClientDetailTemplateId("gridSczegolyNazwa")
 }else{
   .ToClientTemplate() 
 }
)
```

Is it possible to add a condition as in the example above?

Comment: Why not just use the template to apply the conditional logic? I doubt you can do that with the wrapper. Possibly with jquery.

Answer (score 1):

I used an inline if inside the ClientDetailTemplateId and set the false option to "" and it worked for me.

```
.ClientDetailTemplateId(model.useDetailTemplate ? "gridSczegolyNazwa" : "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not, you will need two alternative Grid declarations and the IF statement should be on the outside.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way 
first set hierarchy column display to none :

```
.k-hierarchy-cell {
        display: none;
    }
```

then add a template column like this to create your hierarchy column conditionally :

```
columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate(@"#if(hasHierarchy== true ) {#<a class='k-icon k-i-expand' href='\\#' aria-label='Expand' tabindex='-1'></a>#}#").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-hierarchy-cell-active k-hierarchy-cell" });
```

at the end set this column display to block :

```
.k-hierarchy-cell-active {
        display: block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code on the dataBound event, to hide triangle :

```
function dataBound(e) {
    var items = e.sender.items();
    items.each(function () {
        var row = $(this);
        var dataItem = e.sender.dataItem(row);
        if (dataItem.number != 1) {
            row.find(".k-hierarchy-cell > a.k-icon.k-i-expand").css("visibility", "hidden");
        }
    })                   
}
```

With the above, we check the current 'number' of the master row, and based on its number the triangle is being hidden.